# Adding an extra sidebar to wordpress theme

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have built my own wordpress theme and the structure of the theme is two side bars, one on the left side and the other on the right side, and one main content between them.

So far I have succeded in adding the left sidebar with the code inside the index.php file:

```
<?php
get_header();
if (have_posts()) :
   while (have_posts()) :
      the_post();
      the_content();
   endwhile;
endif;
get_sidebar();
get_footer(); 
?>
```

Now, what do I do to add the second sidebar, the right one?
I would like to be able to pick three different template. One with 1 sidebar, another with 2 sidebars and the third one without any sidebars.
I have already created the template with 1 sidebar and without sidebars. But what I need help with is to create the one with two sidebars.

Thanks!

Comment: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-add-a-sidebar-4 You need to register the new sidebar in `functions.php`, create a sidebar file, `sidebar-right.php` for example.

Answer (score 1):

First register new sidebar, add this code in your functions.php

```
function custom_sidebar() {
    $args = array(
        'id'            => 'left_side',
        'name'          => __( 'left', 'text_domain' ),
        'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widgettitle">',
        'after_title'   => '</h2>',
        'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</li>',
    );
    register_sidebar( $args );

}

// Hook into the 'widgets_init' action
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'custom_sidebar' );
```

and add this in your index.php

```
get_sidebar('left');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can register the sidebar with the below code, add this code inside functions.php

```
<?php

register_sidebar(array(
    'name' => __('Second Front Page Widget Area', 'twentytwelve'),
    'id' => 'sidebar-3',
    'description' => __('Appears when using the optional Front Page template with a page set as Static Front Page', 'twentytwelve'),
    'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget' => '</aside>',
    'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title' => '</h3>',
));

?>
```

You can use this sidebar like

```
<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ); ?>
```